# How to Configure Internal IP for Azure API App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-virtual-network

I have a Azure API App service which needs to be exposed to client with single Internal IP. How can i do this?

Comment: You can create a virtual network with your client.

Comment: You can use an Internal Load Balancer with an App Service Environment to  configure Internal IP for Azure App service. App Service Environment is a Premium service option of Azure App Service that delivers an enhanced configuration capability that is not available in the multi-tenant stamps.See more details to this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-environment-with-internal-load-balancer

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to create the API management service in Internal mode.

See here for more info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-internal-vnet